# What am I doing wrong $_GET

Tags: php, url-parameters

I am trying to get a value from a URL and it's not working. Here is the code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['pag'])) {
    $sel_continut = $_GET['pag'];
} else {
    $sel_continut = "no value sent";
}

echo "<a href=\"continut.php?pag=" . $informatie_tabel['nume_meniu'] . "\">" . $denumire_pagina . "</a> <br />";
```

Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Define "not working".  What do you expect this code to do?  What does it actually do?

Comment: I am expecting to get a the value  from "pag="  now i'm getting  "no value sent"; this means that the "pag" it's not set but it is in the URL right?

Comment: What is the value that you're setting when the page is loaded?  I guess I should also ask the obvious question... You're not trying to get the query string value *before it's being provided* are you?

Comment: The value it's a string from the SQL DB. i have the connection above the code that i's trying to echo. I have also written a code without SQL and stil it's not getting the value from the URL. It's obvious that I'm doing something wrong. This is the code   <?php

  $sel_continut = $_GET['pag'];
 echo "<a href=\"continut.php?pag=test\"> LINK </a> <br />";
 echo $sel_continut;

?>

Comment: How many times are you loading this page?  That is, what is the *exact set of steps* you're using to test this?  I strongly suspect that you're trying to read a query string value *before* it's ever used on a query string.

Comment: First I's testing if is set after that the SQL connection,  the URL and after that echo the value from GET. But why the code without the SQL also does not work?

Comment: `<?php

  $sel_continut = $_GET['pag'];
 echo "<a href=\"continut.php?pag=test\"> LINK </a> <br />";
 echo $sel_continut;

?>`

Comment: I'm not sure how else to ask this... When you *load this page*, what is the URL *in your browser*?

Comment: This is the URL from browser that contains the code `http://localhost/extragere_din_baza_de_date.php` and this is where the link goes `http://localhost/continut.php?pag=Home`. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: can you print `$sel_continut` after `if structure` and show the output? And let us know the URL that you've been visiting?

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comments...

This is the URL being used to load the page:

```
http://localhost/extragere_din_baza_de_date.php
```

Note that there *is no query string value*.  So this code:

```
$_GET['pag']
```

isn't going to find anything.  The value was never set.  So your code is always going to enter the `else` condition.  You later create a link with a query string value:

```
http://localhost/continut.php?pag=Home
```

But that's for *a completely different page* which *hasn't even been requested yet*.  If you reference `$_GET['pag']` on the `continut.php` page's code, then you'll see the value.

What I'm trying to say is... You can't read a query string value before it's been sent.  The good news is that you don't *need* to read this value.  Since you're in the same code which *sets* the value on the link, then clearly you *already have* this value.  Right here:

```
$informatie_tabel['nume_meniu']
```

Comment: I understand so I have changed the `continut.php` with `extragere_din_baza_de_date.php` and I understand that when I access the link `http://localhost/extragere_din_baza_de_date.php` it will get the else statement, but when I click the link in the page and now the link is `http://localhost/extragere_din_baza_de_date?pag=Home` it's saying `Not Found

The requested URL /extragere_din_baza_de_date was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80`

Comment: @SilviuAntohe: It looks like that link is missing the `.php` in the file name.  The link has to point to an actual page, not just something that's similar to a page.

Comment: i forgot the `.php` :) Thank you again for having patience with me.